# How to install Mysql-server in Ubuntu offline

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, offline

I need to install `Mysql-server` in an `Ubuntu 18` machine which do not have any internet access. There are plethora of instruction material exist on this this subject but all they require Ubuntu machine to be online.

One such documentation can be available here (quite comprehensive though)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Any help on offline installation of `Mysql-server` will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ from a computer that can go online.

Then, select your OS and version

[image: MySQL download page]

Download DEB Bundle on a computer that can go online. Move the downloaded file internally to your system that cannot hit the Internet.

[image: Download options]

Your downloaded file will be a .tar. Use command `tar -xvf filename.tar` (See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tar-extract-linux/ for command).

You will get a new directory. `cd that-directory` will get you in that directory. You will see a bunch of .deb files.

Install the deb files one by one using `sudo apt-get install filename.deb` depending on what you want to install. Other commands to install deb files can be found in this discussion https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you follow this guide on how to use apt-offline. https://linoxide.com/debian/install-debian-packages-offline/

As a general guide:

You start by having apt-offline installed on both PCs, this is done by default on the desktop releases, but can easily be installed by just downloading the `.deb` package for your release from the packages.ubuntu.com website: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/apt-offline/download

Then create a signature that can be put onto another PC that'll do the downloading/fetching updates and make a note that we also need mysql-server

```
apt-offline set offline-servers-state.sig --install-packages mysql-server
```

You can then use this signature on a PC connected to the internet using the same tool to check for updates and/or download the required files into a zip file

```
apt-offline get --bundle zip/file/location/bundle.zip offline-servers-state.sig
```

Once downloaded you can put this `.zip` back on the offline server to install the packages

```
apt-offline install zip/file/location/bundle.zip
```

Comment: This is really great information. Thanks for sharing